# Showing that a map is conformal.

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $\sigma : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ such that

$\sigma(x,u) = (x-x^3/3+xy^2,y-y^3/3+yx^2,x^2-y^2)$. Question is to show that this is a conformal map. Our definition is the following:

Let $S_1, S_2$ be a pair of regular surfaces. A diffeomorphism $f : S_1 \rightarrow S_2$ is called conformal if $df$ preserves angles, that is, if
$∠(u, v) = ∠(df_p(u), df_p(v))$ for all $p \in S1$ and all $u, v \in T_pS_1$, where

$∠(df_p(u), df_p(v))=cos^{-1}(\frac{\langle df_p(u), df_p(v) \rangle}{\lvert df_p(u) \rvert \cdot \lvert df_p(v) \rvert})$

I calculated the differential of this map but it is represented as a $3x2$ matrix. How can take the inner product of such matrices? Can you help me with this? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Using $x$ and $y$ for tangent vectors and also for the variables you're using to parametrize the surface is *truly* confusing. But do the linear algebra to verify that if you check the angles match up for the 3 combinations of $\partial\sigma/\partial x$ and $\partial\sigma/\partial y$, then they always match up.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks for the feedback, I edited the confusing parts. I did not understand what do you mean by 3 combinations of them?

Comment: The $u$ in $\sigma(x,u)$ should still be $y$, of course. Use $u=v=\partial\sigma/\partial x$, $u=v=\partial\sigma/\partial y$, and $u=\partial\sigma/\partial x$ together with $v=\partial\sigma/\partial y$.

Comment: @TedShifrin I tried to get him to take his two 3-vectors and make the 2 by 2 Gram matrix of inner products. This was not met with much joy

Comment: @Will: Yes, I saw. I thought using the definition he gave, along with my hint, might help him interpret your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is enough that the **Gram matrix, which is 2 by 2**, be scalar, meaning a (scalar function) multiple of the identity matrix. As you say your differential map is 3 by 2, call it $A,$ you need to just multiply to get
$$   G = A^T A $$
The entries of $G$ are just dot products of vectors (each with three entries)

Comment: Okay, I can do this, thanks. But why? I do not know the theory behind this solution. Can you explain more?